# Error Event registration - When registering for an event

Tags: wordpress

This is all that is on the page after you click "Continue"

**Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Could not find valid value for id
Return to home page.**

Using civicrm 4.7.8 with Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you start on a different domain name or protocol than the one configured in civi.

a common issue is to go to http://example.org but http://www.example.org is configured, or https://example.org

Can you copy/paste the url of the registration form and the one after? are they the same?